# ZendFramework - How to get the database insert error and stop auto redirection to error page?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

Trying to insert row, and it fails to insert because of duplicate key found. And throws to error page. But how do i avoid going to error page but simply get the error result? so that i can echo it.

```
$db->insert("university", $data);
$lastID = $db->lastInsertId();
# when it fails to insert
# how can i run this echo
echo $theCauseOfErrorOnlyDoNotRedirectToError; //??
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should use a try catch block

```
try {
    $db->insert("university", $data);
    $lastID = $db->lastInsertId();
} catch(Exception $e) {
   // when it fails to insert
   // how can i run this echo
   echo $theCauseOfErrorOnlyDoNotRedirectToError; //??
}
```

You can review the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) about exceptions and exception handling.

Comment: Thanks for this code, might want to `var_dump($e->getMessage());` inside the catch. Just a note for newbies.